# Replacing Duplicate values inside Set in Java instead of rejecting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, set

I have to insert data inside Set in Java code.

To identify duplicates based on id in entity, I have overridden equals and hashcode method.
Now, the values with duplicate id are rejected when trying to add inside Set.

Present behavior - Set rejects new data with id already existing in Set
Expected: How to make Set replace the new duplicate values with the same id instead of rejecting? [similar to Map which replaces duplicate key ]

Thanks

Comment: Override the `add` with your own method which removes if it exists, before adding?

Comment: Your object `equals` method should not be solely based on `id` in this case, or explicitly call `contains` before `add`

Comment: What kind of Set? HashSet is backed by a HashMap and should behave as you describe.